# How to extract domain name from email address and add it to a new column in a pipe delimited file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, gawk

I have a pipe-delimited file with an email address in the third column. I need help to create the fourth column out of the domain name from the email address in the third column using awk or sed command.

**Input file**

```
TEST|1234|john.doe@gmail.com
TEST|4533|jeffp12@yahoo.com
TEST|9030|indoep13@gmx.com
TEST|0903|ramdpe23@gmail.com
```

**Expected output**

```
TEST|1234|john.doe@gmail.com|gmail.com
TEST|4533|nobody1@yahoo.com|yahoo.com
TEST|9030|mailmejeff@gmx.com|gmx.com
TEST|0903|ramdpe23@gmail.com|gmail.com
```

Comment: [edit] your question to tell us: What have you tried? What problem did you experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk -F '@' '{print $0"|"$NF}' file

TEST|1234|john.doe@gmail.com|gmail.com
TEST|4533|jeffp12@yahoo.com|yahoo.com
TEST|9030|indoep13@gmx.com|gmx.com
TEST|0903|ramdpe23@gmail.com|gmail.com
```

Comment: Just tried but this did not work. Here is a sample output. |gmail.com.TEST|ohn.doe@gmail.com

Comment: @Bala you have DOS line endings, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001

Comment: Thank you.That's correct I had to run this sed to change the line endings to unix. sed -i 's/\r//g'

Comment: @Bala you can also use the `dos2unix` to convert...

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/@\(.*\)/&|\1/' file
TEST|1234|john.doe@gmail.com|gmail.com
TEST|4533|jeffp12@yahoo.com|yahoo.com
TEST|9030|indoep13@gmx.com|gmx.com
TEST|0903|ramdpe23@gmail.com|gmail.com
```

This would match the first `@` character on each line and capture everything after it with a capture group.  The matched text would be replaced by itself followed by the captured text, with a `|` character in-between.

If your file is a DOS text file (as indicated by some of the comments), then you can handle the conversion to a Unix text file in one and the same command:

```
$ sed -e 's/[[:cntrl:]]$//' -e 's/@\(.*\)/&|\1/' file
TEST|1234|john.doe@gmail.com|gmail.com
TEST|4533|jeffp12@yahoo.com|yahoo.com
TEST|9030|indoep13@gmx.com|gmx.com
TEST|0903|ramdpe23@gmail.com|gmail.com
```

The 2nd substitution is the same as before, but the first will remove any control character at the very end of the line (this would remove a carriage return character at the end of each line, if there was one).  The output of this last command will be a Unix text document regardless of whether the original file was a DOS or Unix text file.

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below script

```
for i in `cat o.txt`; do y=`echo $i |awk -F "|" '{print $NF}'| awk -F "@" '{print $NF}'`; echo $i | awk -v y="$y"  '{print $0"|"y}'; done
```

output

```
TEST|1234|john.doe@gmail.com|gmail.com
TEST|4533|jeffp12@yahoo.com|yahoo.com
TEST|9030|indoep13@gmx.com|gmx.com
TEST|0903|ramdpe23@gmail.com|gmail.com
```